# Graphhopper - incorrect location index version

Tags: android, graphhopper, mapsforge

Unable to load the graph data, the library throw a warning about index version:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: incorrect location index version, expected:96230
W/System.err:     at com.graphhopper.storage.index.LocationIndexTree.loadExisting(LocationIndexTree.java:253)
W/System.err:     at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.createLocationIndex(GraphHopper.java:1126)
W/System.err:     at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.initLocationIndex(GraphHopper.java:1141)
W/System.err:     at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.postProcessing(GraphHopper.java:831)
W/System.err:     at com.graphhopper.GraphHopper.load(GraphHopper.java:747)
W/System.err:     at com.dispatcher.driver.service.TrackerService$GraphhopperLoader.doInBackground(TrackerService.java:3205)
W/System.err:     at com.dispatcher.driver.service.TrackerService$GraphhopperLoader.doInBackground(TrackerService.java:3188)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I pulled the latest changes form the repository and generated a new graph, also I used version 0.12.0 and 0.12-SNAPSHOT but the error keeps popping

```
implementation 'com.graphhopper:graphhopper-core:0.12-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.graphhopper:graphhopper-core:0.12.0'
```

Comment: Ok, seems there is version **0.13-SNAPSHOT**

Comment: Make sure you do the import with the same version that you use on Android. Also never use snapshots!

Comment: @Karussell I ran import using graphhopper 0.12, but for some reason android only works if I use graphhopper:0.13-SNAPSHOT. Also I ran **mvn clean install -DskipTests=true** but I can se it is using 0.12-SNAPSHOT.